# Nivo Lightbox notopening on an iPhone, but does work on iPad

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, nivo-slider

Here is a URL with images that you can test this out on:

http://www.imageworkshop.com/2013/06/19/dance-performer-promo-photography/

**To be clear - at one point, all these images were opening on my iPhone in the Nivo lightbox.** But it has been inconsistent. For a while, some blog post images would open, others would not.

At present, none of them seem to be opening in the nivo lightbox on the iPhone - it is however, working on the iPad?!

The following code in my header is relevant to the Nivo Lightbox (initiating the lightbox and also adding swipe functionality):

```
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){          
            jQuery('a.jig-link').nivoLightbox({effect: 'slideRight'});
            jQuery('.lightbox').nivoLightbox({effect: 'slideRight'});                   
    });
    </script>       
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script>    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('body').touchwipe({
            wipeLeft: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-next").click(); },
            wipeRight: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-prev").click(); },
             min_move_x: 70,
             min_move_y: 70,                 
             preventDefaultEvents: false                 
        });
    });     
    </script>
```

This is an example of how the images are wrapped up. If you have any suggestions on why this isn't working I'd appreciate the help!

```
<div id="attachment_2143" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 570px">
<a class="lightbox" title="Dance performers: promotional dance photography" 
 data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" href="http://www.imageworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/13006-0047-Image-Workshop-Melbourne-photography.jpg">
<img class="size-large wp-image-2143 " width="560" height="560" src="http://www.imageworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/13006-0047-Image-Workshop-Melbourne-photography-560x560.jpg" alt="Promotional dance photography by Sharon Blance of the Image Workshop" title="Promotional dance photography by Sharon Blance of the Image Workshop">
</a>
<p class="wp-caption-text">Pete & Steph</p>
</div>
```

NIVO LIGHTBOX DETAILS:
The javascript can be viewed here: https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Lightbox/blob/master/nivo-lightbox.js

CSS can be viewed here: https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Lightbox/blob/master/nivo-lightbox.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have resolved itself. I have also upgrade to the new v1.1 of the NIVO LIGHTBOX plugin, which might also be helping (although this was not the direct resolution to the issue)